# Geting a CAPTCHA image from the browser into a picture box

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, captcha, picturebox

I have a site (http://valfajr5.rozblog.com) which has a CAPTCHA image which I want to get it into a picture box (at the run time program). I have this CAPTCHA:

```
<img width="67" height="20" src="/include/captcha/cap7.php?name_sess=link_auto" title="کد امنیتی" alt="کد امنیتی" id="im_link">
```

How should I do this using VB.NET?

Comment: You don't appear to have shown any effort in trying to solve this yourself. Show the code you already have and read the How to Ask page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have find the code!

```
Dim elem As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("im_sec")
   Dim cap As Object = WebBrowser1.Document.DomDocument.bOdy.createControlRange()
   cap.Add(elem.DomElement)
   cap.execCommand("Copy")
   PictureBox1.Image = My.Computer.Clipboard.GetImage
```